# Only react to last `dbus-monitor` event within a group

Tags: bash, dbus

I'm writing a script to react to `dbus-monitor` but there are a group of 17 events logged in 8/100th of a second. I don't want to react to all 17 events. Only the last event assuming another event doesn't occur within a second or two.

I'm not sure how to code this in bash though?

Sample event log (condensed with grep):

```
$ cat "dbus-monitor-plugin.txt" | grep time= | grep xrandr
method call time=1538331767.151461 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1242 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.151706 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1248 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.152338 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1252 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sony_SONY_TV___00_16843009_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.152597 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1255 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_eDP_1_1_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.152606 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1256 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.156892 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1263 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sony_SONY_TV___00_16843009_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.157062 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1264 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_eDP_1_1_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.157095 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1267 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.157699 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1271 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sony_SONY_TV___00_16843009_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.157707 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1272 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_eDP_1_1_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.158672 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1280 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.158788 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1284 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sony_SONY_TV___00_16843009_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.158954 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1286 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_eDP_1_1_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.159344 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1289 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.159867 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1295 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Sony_SONY_TV___00_16843009_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.159946 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1296 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_eDP_1_1_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
method call time=1538331767.159979 sender=:1.59 -> destination=:1.11 serial=1299 path=/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Toshiba_America_Info_Systems_Inc_TSB_TV_rick_1000; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=GetAll
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, at a high level? Doing it in bash by parsing `dbus-monitor` output is almost certainly not the right way to go about things. Writing a Python program which uses the same match rules as you have configured `dbus-monitor` to use is probably a better bet.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Ubuntu resets external monitors to full brightness and full gamma whenever lid closed on laptop, or resuming from suspend or even replugging monitors. I've covered all the other aspects except replugging or turning monitor off/on. My set of scripts set briightness and gamma for laptop and two external monitors based on internet sunrise and sunset time for users city.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall My concerns are can bash react quickly enough to 17 events in .008 second in calling a script that would wait until last event? Could it even write to a FIFO pipe file that quickly? Does `dbus-monitor` in a loop queue up RAM based events to trickle back to the bash script? I think those dbus events must be RAM based and my NVMe SSD isn't that fast. All-in-all I'm leaning toward FIFO pipe and another bash script to read it and rationalize with other events recorded for ACPI lid close monitoring (already in place) and `/etc/systemd/system-sleep` monitoring (also in place)

Comment: You’d definitely be better off writing this as a Python program. This is far beyond what bash is designed to be used for.