# What is faster for granular time stamping than `date` command?

Tags: bash, performance, date

I want to capture current epoch seconds and milliseconds in format `ssss.mmmm` but the `date` command is too slow:

```
$ for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )) ; do  date +%s.%N ; done
1538521026.143982969
1538521026.146270691
1538521026.148806576
1538521026.151304509
1538521026.153807045
1538521026.155896084
1538521026.158007167
1538521026.160137840
1538521026.162211968
1538521026.164414690

$ date +%s.%N ; for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )) ; do : ; done ; date +%s.%N 
1538523316.866529880
1538523316.867813697
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this.  My first thought was: "So don't use shell-script !".  You will receive better quality answers with more information in your question.  Is there a possibility to write a small program in C/Java/Python instead?

Comment: @Kingsley I want to time-stamp a FIFO pipe stored on `/dev/shm` written to by multiple processes and want the quickest way of getting current time. `dbus-monitor` can log 17 events in .008 seconds, `date` command is way too slow in comparison as shown above. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581787/only-react-to-last-dbus-monitor-event-within-a-group?noredirect=1#comment92150747_52581787

Comment: You don't demonstrate in your sample output how the date command is too slow, just that it takes 2,5 ms. What is "too slow" exactly? What would be "quick enough"?

Comment: @xhienne I thought I demonstrated in the second `for` loop with `date` command outside the loop. Instead of 2.5ms it is .1 ms. I've been searching for awhile and there just doesn't seem to be a bash built-in or shell built-in for getting the current time in ssss.mmm format.

Comment: I know what you demonstrated but that's not what I'm asking: What would be "quick enough"?

Comment: `bash` is simply the wrong tool for job; even if it had a way to get a timestamp with millisecond accuracy, you probably couldn't actually read the input from `/dev/shm` quickly enough for your needs.

Comment: @chepner A slower program that works over 2 to 10 seconds will read the FIFO pipe stored on /dev/shm. Three other processes will write to the FIFO pipe. I just wanted timestamps for ACPI (Lid close), DBUS (color mangement Xrandr Find) and systemd (suspend) recorded to the FIFO pipe with granularity. It is DBUS monitor which is giving the fastest signals requiring speed. The `date` external command can't keep up to `dbus-monitor` speed. This could be a golden opportunity to write my first C program as a bash built-in called "timestamp". The more I think about it the more fun it starts to sound.

Comment: Well, Bash's `printf '(%s)T\n' -1` (Bash 4.2 and newer) is *much* faster, but unfortunately doesn't have nanoseconds as a formatting option (at least not on my system's `strftime(3)`).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I forgot to check out `printf` being a built-in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ts` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
$ for i in {1..10};do echo;done|ts  "%.s"
1538533686.931192 
1538533686.931273 
1538533686.931298 
1538533686.931335 
1538533686.931376 
1538533686.931413 
1538533686.931439 
1538533686.931462 
1538533686.931486 
1538533686.931508
```

Comment: Now we are talking. It's even faster whey you type `hash ts` first.